# ¿Cómo actualizar un inventario en cada actualización?

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de hacer que 2 inventarios sean siempre los mismos pero para diferentes sucursales, algo como idPrimaria=1,idProducto=1,idSucursal=1 y Existencias=10, entonces idPrimaria=2,idProducto=1,idSucursal=2 y Existencias= debe quedar como 10 para que las existencias siempre tenga el mismo numero. Si cambio la existencia en idPrimaria=1 a 7 entonces las existencias del idPrimaria=2 tendria que actualizarse a 7 y viceversa. Se que la implementación está mal pero solo busco la solución más rápida ya que tiene años en producción. Lo estoy intentando con trigger pero se cicla, es decir, cada que se intenta actualizar pues entra el trigger. Mysql evita eso y me sale un error ***#1442 - Can't update table 't1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger***

```
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.idSucursal=1) THEN
        UPDATE inventario set iExistencia=new.iExistencia where idProducto=new.idProducto and idSucursal=2;
    ELSEIF (old.idSucursal=2) THEN
        UPDATE inventario set iExistencia=new.iExistencia where idProducto=new.idProducto and idSucursal=1;
    END IF;
END
```

También estoy probando con este

```
BEGIN
  bucle: LOOP
  IF(new.iExistencia=old.iExistencia) THEN
    LEAVE bucle;
  end IF;
  IF(OLD.idSucursal=1) THEN
        UPDATE inventario set iExistencia=new.iExistencia where idProducto=new.idProducto and idSucursal=2;
 ELSEIF(OLD.idSucursal=2) THEN
        UPDATE inventario set iExistencia=new.iExistencia where idProducto=new.idProducto and idSucursal=1;
 END IF;
end LOOP ;
END
```

Pero me marca el mismo problema.

¿Será posible corregir este problema?

Gracias a todos por su tiempo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Parecería que quieres que el TRIGGER se ejecute sobre la misma tabla ¿? Pero luego hablas de *que sea una copia la una de la otra*, ¿qué una de qué otra, hablas de tablas, hablas de columnas? ¿Qué significa que *se cicla*?

Comment: @A.Cedano El trigger se ejecuta sobre la misma tabla. Hablo de columnas, algo como idPrimaria=1,idProducto=1,idSucursal=1 y Existencias=10, entonces idPrimaria=2,idProducto=1,idSucursal=2 y Existencias= debe quedar como 10 para que el producto siempre tenga el mismo inventario. Cada que se actualiza la existencia debería modificarse la otra, pero se cicla, es decir, cada que se intenta actualizar pues entra el trigger. Mysql evita eso y me sale un error #1442 - Can't update table 't1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: @BetaM lo se, pero la base de datos no estaba escalable y ahora se requiere compartir el inventario. No es mi base de datos, solo me pidieron ayuda, siento que casi lo logro pero quizá estoy muy lejos. No se puede modificar la base de datos porque ya está en producción hace años.

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta y agrega el código faltante (que creo pusiste en un comentario) así como todos los demás detalles que consideres por favor

Comment: Si es sobre la misma tabla, MySQL no te permite modificar la misma tabla que lanzó el TRIGGER. Deberás hacerlo de otro modo, por ejemplo, creando un Stored Procedure y llamándola desde dentro del TRIGGER. De todos modos es una práctica cuestionable y tarde o temprano habrá que plantearse rediseñar cosas en la base de datos, un diseño mal hecho casi siempre termina dando problemas.

Comment: @A.Cedano si lo se, entiendo que está mal diseñada pero solo busco la solución más rápida. Entiendo lo del Stored Procedure pero al final creo que tendría el mismo error ¿no? Bueno, agradezco tu tiempo y seguiré investigando. Disculpa la molestia.

Comment: La cuestión aquí es que en MySQL **no puedes absolutamente modificar la misma tabla que dispara el TRIGGER**, por tanto debes buscar otra forma de hacerlo. Aunque leyendo la pregunta actualizada no logro entender lo que quieres lograr. Si lo explicas un poco más claro quizá podamos dilucidar si se puede hacer de otro modo, incluso evitando el TRIGGER.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que ya lo explico mejor. Siento que estoy cerca pero es posible que sea imposible. En realidad Mysql hace lo correcto al prevenir estas cosas.

Comment: _A MySQL no le gustan los bucles infinitos de actualizaciones_

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿entones por más que valide no se va a dejar? ¿No existe la posibilidad?

Comment: Cambiar algo en la tabla A no debería disparar un evento de cambio en la tabla A. No es fácil garantizar transacciones ACID en esas cadenas. Además, cada motor maneja los bloqueos de tabla de una u otra forma en estos eventos BEFORE/AFTER loquesea. En general, esto que buscas debería pasar de otra forma. Posiblemente tu diseño no es bueno y, si la cantidad debe ser la misma para todas las sucursales, significa que esa cantidad no debería estar en la misma tupla que la idSucursal... con eso, el inventarioTotal sería uno solo y lo verían igual desde cualquier sucursal.

Comment: @Alfabravo Te lo agradezco, entiendo porque no funciona. Si, el diseño está mal pero pues tengo que trabajar sobre eso. Muchas gracias por todo.